# How to hide and show textfield on checkbox in extjs

Tags: extjs

I am trying to show and hide the textfield in extjs, I am unable to toggle this
Here is my code below.

```
        xtype : 'checkbox',
        fieldLabel : 'Is WGVPN',
        id : 'isWGVPN-id',
        listeners:
        {
            change: function()
            {
                showGVPNCaseAsPerScenario(Ext.getCmp('isWGVPN-id').getvalue,Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id'));
                if(Ext.getCmp('isWGVPN-id').getvalue==true)
                {
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').disable();
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').hide();
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(false);  
                }
                else
                {
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').enable();
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').show();
                    Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').up('.x-form-item').setDisplayed(true);  

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just change Ext.getCmp('isWGVPN-id').getvalue to Ext.getCmp('isWGVPN-id').getValue()
[see fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/16qc)

Comment: Its working though but not reloading the changes, to see changes I am moving my window

Comment: You can try to make and updateLayout() in order to see the changes

Comment: As a side note: Stop using `Ext.getCmp()` inside listeners for the triggering component. Use `this` instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
xtype      : 'checkbox',   
fieldLabel : 'Is WGVPN',  
id         : 'isWGVPN-id',   
listeners: 
{   
    change: function(newValue,OldValue) {    
        if(newValue== true){      
            Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').setVisible(false);   
        } else{   
            Ext.getCmp('ethFreeVCGNumber-id').setVisible(true);   
        }   
    }
}
```

Use this code.